# Laravel eager model loading with custom attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there any possible way to get a custom attribute value through eager load

For instance, given this custom attribute on a model:

```
class User extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['is_member'];

    public function getIsMemberAttribute() {
        return 'yes';
    }
}
```

and related model

```
class Awards extends Model {

    public function owner(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }

}
```

I would love to be able to get `is_member` attribute in collection using request below:

```
$users=Awards::orderBy('created_at')->with('owner')->get();
```

Comment: When you do `$users->toArray()`, there will be `is_member` attribute in `owner` node. So whats the question here?

Comment: @Amit when i do dd($users) there are all attributes corresponding to users db table but there is no is_member attribute

Comment: This is normal behavior and I don't find any use case where you need this. Give some examples why you need this, maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1):

According to Laravel's [documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json), `$appends` is used for appending in array and JSON only...

> Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will be included in both the model's array and JSON forms.

So, when you do something like `dd($user)`. You will not be able to see the `is_member` field, but when you do something like `$user->toArray()` or `$user->toJson()` you will.

Basically, for places wherever `is_member` field is always present. All you need to do to access it is (say in Page View/Blade etc)

```
public function show($id) {
  $user = User::get($id);

  return view('users.show', ['user' => $user->toArray()]);
}
```

And then do,

```
Is Member? : {{ $user['is_member'] }}

// Or if you don't like blade you can do this
// Is Member? : <?php echo $user['is_member'] ?>
```

But as written in the comments by @Amit, there is no use case of this until you are using it for the sole purpose of **APIs**. For blade etc, you should prefer doing this

```
Is Member? : {{ $user->is_member ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}

// Again if you don't like blade you can do this
// Is Member? : <?php echo $user['is_member'] ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?>
```

Hope this clears your doubts :)